# Error on android detected when i deployed my app with expo

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

After the pre-launch test report on Android, Android detect one error :

```
Exception java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: expo.modules.kotlin.jni.JavaCallback.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
  at com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor.deleteNative
  at com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor.destruct (HybridData.java:81)
  at com.facebook.jni.HybridData.resetNative (HybridData.java:48)
  at expo.modules.kotlin.jni.JavaCallback.finalize (JavaCallback.kt:41)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:291)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:278)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:139)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```

I don't know how to reproduce this and why i have this error ? Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a bare or an managed app? What react-native and expo version are you using?

Comment: expo version 47 and it is a  managed app

Comment: The problem seems to be related to https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19259 but this post is about bare projects.